# (AS3) MovieClip' s motion path as Shape on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a game for a school project. The concept is pretty simple, you need to fix the circuit wires(the path in the form of rectangular shapes) so that electricity can run through the circuit and light up the bulbs.

I'm trying to find a way on how you can make a movie clip travel the wires. I have seen a lot of tutorials where they state coordinates and angles for the motion path but I want to make it so that the movie clip will automatically follow the shape path present on the stage so even if the path changes(for different levels), the movie clip will still follow that path. As of the moment, all I can do is create a predefined guide path inside the movie clip which traces the path.

Follow-up question:
Is there also a way on how I can detect if the shape path is complete or not? The system will check whether or not the wires are connected to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instead do a metadata calculation prior to moving something you intend, this way you first calculate whether your puzzle is solved, once it is, or once you have determined the point where your movable object should stop and display the error, you then make a path out of simple sections, then make your object move by them one by one until final point, then display the outcome. This is the general idea. A simple code of moving an object by sections looks like this:

```
var sections:Vector.<Point>; // we need x&y sequence. Fill this prior to launching the routine
var position:int=0; // where are we now
var velocity:int=8; // pixels per frame, adjust as needed
movable.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveABit);
function moveABit(e:Event):void {
    var nextPoint:Point=sections[position];
    var do:DisplayObject=e.target as DisplayObject; // what we are moving
    var here:Point=new Point(do.x,do.y);
    if (Point.distance(here,nextPoint)<velocity) {
        // this means we are too close to interpolate, just place
        do.x=nextPoint.x;
        do.y=nextPoint.y;
        position++;
        if (position>=sections.length) {
            // movement finished
            // TODO make your final animation
            do.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveABit); // stop moving
        }
    } else {
        // interpolate movement
        var angle:Number=Math.atan2(nextPoint.y-here.y,nextPoint.x-here.x);
        do.x+=Math.cos(angle)*velocity;
        do.y+=Math.sin(angle)*velocity; 
        // if the object will move to wrong direction, fix this code!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was hoping that the system can automatically detect the shape path and just travel on it but I guess I have to manually tell it where the path is and where to turn.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if your 'shape' is complete:
You can create a vector of boolean variables(every variable indicate a node of your wires- you set the variable to true when is connected), and you need a function to check if all the vars from vector are true (with loop), that means your shape is complete. Hope this idea helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Can you show me a sample code of what you mean? Because I get the logic, it's just that I can't think of how I'll put it in code. Also, I'm a bit of a beginner at this so Vector's are a new thing for me (from what I understand, it's a better form of Arrays).